# how remove XML Node with java

Tags: java, xml, dom

i need to remove the "Object" tag, but I need to preserve and keep the content. Is that possible?

```
<ds:KeyInfo>
    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        <wsse:Reference URI="#b3f74c53-b79f-4dec-aa26-ca552f8f8745"/>
    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:Object Id="id1"> // <-Remove this
    <wsu:Timestamp>
        <wsu:Created>2017-03-28T20:21:44Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2017-03-28T23:08:24Z</wsu:Expires>
    </wsu:Timestamp>
 </ds:Object>  // <-Remove this
```

I tried:

```
Node node = xml.getElementById("id1");
xml.getDocumentElement().removeChild(node);
```

but:

```
Org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist.
```

Comment: Please clarify. are you trying to change `<ds:Object Id="id1"> ... </ds:Object>` to `<ds Id="id1"> ... </ds>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, only the parent of the node to be removed can remove it:

```
Node nodeToBeRemoved = xmlDoc.getElementById("id1");
Node parentNode = nodeToBeRemoved.getParentNode();
Node removedNode = parentNode.removeChild(nodeToBeRemoved);
```

Second, in order to "preserve and keep the content" you will need to attach the children elements of the removed one to its parent:

```
NodeList removedChildren = removedNode.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0 ; i < removedChildren.getLength(); i++) {
    Node child = removedChildren.item(i);
    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        parentNode.appendChild(child);
    }
}
```